# docker-compose - COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME, DockerHub and "service name". How to use it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tags

I'm using `docker-compose` to built customised `nginx` and `php` images and then I'd like to `push` it to DockeHub.

I'm using `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` in an `.env` file to set a prefix image name:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myapp
```

and `docker-compose.yml` is something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
      args:
         .....
      volumes:
         .....
      expose:
         .....

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      args:
         .....
      volumes:
         .....
      port:
         .....
```

Running `docker-compose up -d` the images name are:

```
myapp_nginx
myapp_php-fpm
```

the container name are:

```
myapp_nginx_1
myapp_php-fpm_1
```

Now, to push these images to DocekeHub I need to change image name adding the DockerHub "account" suffix:

```
myaccount/myapp_nginx
myaccount/myapp_php-fpm
```

to solve this problem, I added the "image" option to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
      args:
         .....
      volumes:
         .....
      expose:
         .....
      image: myaccount/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_php-fpm

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      args:
         .....
      volumes:
         .....
      port:
         .....
      image: myaccount/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_nginx
```

now, running `docker-compose push` the images are pushed to DockerHub.

Ok, my question are:

1) is there a way to insert DockerHub account name `myaccout` into `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` variable? Something like: `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myaccount/myapp` to create automatically the image name like: `myaccount/myapp_nginx` and `myaccount/myapp_php-fpm`?

2) is there a variable to get "service name" the retrieve the name `nginx` or `php-fpm`? 
For example, into the `docker-compose.yml` file, I could set: `image: myaccount/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_<service_name>` then If I change the "service name" from `nginx` to `nginx2` automatically the image will be `myaccount/myapp_nginx2`

3) is there a way to rename the images produced with `docker-compose` only to permit the `push`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically use fixed image names in this context.  A published image name shouldn't be dependent on details of the specific Compose file that launched it.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: myaccount/nginx # no project name
```

Imagine you're planning to run this same setup on a different system.  It has Docker and Compose installed, but none of your application source code.  You should be able to copy the `docker-compose.yml` file there, delete the `build:` line, and run the same thing.  It doesn't matter if the directory is named `project` or `other`, and it doesn't matter if the Compose setup actually names the service `proxy` instead of `nginx`; you'd use the same `image:` to refer to it.

```yaml
# COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=other
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: myaccount/nginx # same image as above
```

If you're unhappy with the names Compose produces, you can manually `docker tag` and `docker push` the images outside of Compose.  You'll also need to do this if you want an image to have multiple tags (both a date stamp and `latest` for example) or if for whatever reason you need to push it to multiple repositories (both Docker Hub and Amazon ECR).